# Get SOAP request body in proxy client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have application which calls a WCF service. For monitoring and tracking purposes I would like to have log all request messages for which application failed to call a service. Loke I need to call operation called RemoveSubscription and once failed(may be network problem or WCF service was down) I would like to log the SOAP message into xml or txt file.

Generaly is it possible to get the request SOAP contact in proxy class.

I found some info that it can be done by extending SoapExtension class. If this is the right way how to register/inject the new class which extends SoapExtension to channel stack.

EDIT : Service is not hosted in IIS it is in Windows service... so I am i right that in this case SoapExtension is not the right solution.

Comment: `SoapExtension` is not for WCF. Look up "wcf tracing".

Comment: @John yes you are right SoapExtension is seems to be only for ASP.NET web services. As for tracing I didn't found how to achieve it using tracing capabilities. So I have concentrated on interceptors.

Comment: You can also do it using message logging, but interceptors are more thorough.

Comment: @John it would be interesting also try with message logging. Can you give me more direction on this. The main requirement for me is to log SOAP messages only for failed calles.

Comment: I haven't seen a use of message logging for "conditional" logging, but see [Message Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731859.aspx).

Comment: @John Thank you. I will check, may be there is some way. Also I think it would be done using DataContractSerilizer as all my request response objects ara DataContract classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a WCF based client, you can create an endpoint behavior to intercept the request & response messages. This [TechNet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/how-to-inspect-wcf-message-headers-using-iclientmessageinspector.aspx) shows how to access the message being sent and the response message. Your WCF client can be generated by either adding a Service Reference in Visual Studio, using SvcUtil to manually generate your client code or rolling your own proxy directly in code using the ChannelFactory class.

Your logging code would always write out the request message with a status of requested and a timestamp to some data store (file, database, etc.) When the response message is received, it would match request message somehow from the response message contents and update the data store to change the status to responded. Selecting all the messages from the data store with the status of requested older that some time period would list all the failed messages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helps alot. Now I can get all requests and responses. And the only thing is left to find out how to log only the failed requests. Would it be possible to store the request in some variable in BeforeSendRequest and then once AfterReceiveReply is received with fault, log it.

Comment: The threading model of the application the WCF client is running from will determine if it safe to use private class variables to store what you need. By default the IClientMessageInspector implementation is **not** thread-safe. If your app is single threaded you should be OK. Also, making asynchronous calls to the service may complicate thread safety.

Comment: Thank you for your time Sixto you really helped me on this.